# Increasing the PWM voltage level from 1.8V to 3.3V

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, driver, gate-driving

I need PWM pulses of 3.3V, and my micro-controller is giving 1.8V PWM signals. I have a voltage source of 3.3V. One way I am thinking is to use two cascaded inverters(like NOT-GATE) using MOSFETs. Is there any other good ways to do this?

Comment: You could use a single MOSFET or BJT.

Comment: How would I do with one?

Comment: You can often invert the PWM polarity in the microcontroller and use a single inverter (or transistor in common-emitter mode) for level shift.

Answer (score 2):

Logic level converter: -

[image]

This one works with two Vcc levels from 0.8V to 3.6V.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a bi-directional voltage-level translation device.
Here are some from [ti](http://www.ti.com/logic/docs/translationresults.tsp?sectionId=458&voltageIn=1.8&searchDirection=2&voltageOut=3.3#voltintf), [analog](http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/level-translators/products/index.html) and [maxim](http://www.maximintegrated.com/products/interface/level-translators/high-speed.cfm).